# Using Zsh instead of Bash on a particular Ubuntu server --- Just change, or fully reinstall?

Tags: command-line, bash, apache2, zsh

Is changing root's shell from Bash to Zsh in a Ubuntu machine with a basic server environment a dangerous step to take?

By basic server environment I mean: LAMP, PHPmyadmin, CSF-LFD, Maldet, Make).

I thought of fully reinstalling the server environment this time with Zsh but when I install Ubuntu in my Hosting platform - DigitalOcean it automatically comes with Bash.

The server environment setup script I use to actually establish a good, stable server environment usually includes these (besides various `apt-get`s):

heredocuments (especially cat heredocs), `sed` operations, `awk` operations, `wget`s, `echo` strings, bash strings (see an example in advance), hash comments, etc. Should these things work regularly in Zsh too?

By Bash string I mean, for example:

```
bash -c "echo 'alias www=\"cd /var/www/html\"' >> /etc/bash.bashrc"
```

Note: The reason I consider working with Zsh is to enjoy the **preexec** behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling all the environment is IMHO an overkill. [`zsh` is a package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=zsh) like many others, you can just run `sudo apt install zsh` and use it.

I haven’t tested `zsh` personally yet but it should make no difference when using external commands like `apt-get`, `sed`, `awk`, `wget` and so on. You should check the support of shell features like *heredoc* and `echo` (which is internal command in Bash). Your “Bash string” should work as long as you don’t uninstall Bash (don’t do it) but it probably wouldn’t affect `zsh`.

Of course, you should test the changes (like any others) before you deploy them in the production environment.